# How to improve performance on a .net wcf service

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, performance, appharbor

I'm porting a cpu-heavy .net 4.0 windows application to a .net 4.0 wcf service. Basically I just imported the .net classes to the wcf service.

All is working well except for performance at the wcf service - a task that takes 6267947 ticks (2539ms) uses 815349861 ticks (13045ms) on the aspx.net wcf service running locally on the same develop machine.

I allready have uploaded the service + a test client to appharbor where the performance is as bad as on my local machine - the link to my test app is: [http://www.wsolver.com/](http://www.wsolver.com). Any ideas on how I can improve performance?

Comment: What type of work does your service have to do?

Comment: @Johnny Graber its a scrabble solver. it loads a large dictionary into a trie structure in memory where a lot of lookup is going on

Comment: The actual *doing* code should take the same time. The switch to WCF should only impact transport issues, assuming you aren't using sync-context etc. Can you clarify: where is that time measured? "doing" code? Or transport? Or...?

Comment: @Marc Gravell The transport is minimal but anyway - the benchmark is measured on the same spot in both situations, ie. "doing code". Could it be that the service does not have allocated enough memory to hold the dictionary trie

Comment: I hit your test site link 3 times, and all 3 requests took 2.1 to 2.5 seconds, which is what you said is the "good" performing metric (2539ms).  Did you hit your WCF service multiple times and throw-out the lowest and highest number to get an average? If you just hit it once, then I could see the 1st hit taking 13 seconds, especially if it was IIS hosted and the 1st hit.

Comment: @rally25rs my test case that took around 13sec for the service and 2.5sec for the windows app were with more rack letters than the default (sorry if this were not clear from the question)

Comment: Do you load the data structure on each request? If so, you should consider loading it just once in `Application_Start()`.

Comment: @friism tak! caching the dictionary trie on application_start for some reason has improved performance, now the wcf service runs just as fast as the windows app locally - the online apphb version is around three times slower. I guess this has to do with assigned cpu resources

Comment: @Muleskinner Great, glad that helped. Initializing the datastructure (if that is costly) just once in `Application_Start()` will greatly improve performance compared to doing the initialization in each request.

Comment: @Muleskinner I've this suggestion as an answer below, please accept if you think it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do time-consuming initialization of a complex datastructure, you should to that once in `Application_Start()` and assign the generated datastructure to a static variable on the MvcApplication object. Doing it just once on application start is going to be much faster that doing it in each request.

Comment: Thanks, would you say that the performance discrepancy in running the wcf service locally vs running it online at appharbor (3 times slower in calculating, not taking network traffic in consideration) can be explained by lack of sufficient CPU resources on appharbor. If so, could the performance be optimized by purchasing extra workers?

Comment: Purchasing additional workers will not increase individual request response time, but will increase total request throughput because you get additional concurrency. We are considering whether adding higher-powered individual workers is something we should do. You might want to consider whether doing resource-intensive processing like this in synchronous requests is appropriate and whether maybe moving this to asynchronous AJAX request might be better.

Answer (score 3):

Check any dependencies on your service that may be constructed at Request Time. These Include constructor dependencies and field/property dependencies. Maybe one of them is causing the delay?  If this is the case consider using a singleton to instantiate the long running class.

Have you confirmed that subsequent requests still cause the delay?

Also create a band new service that does something simple like Datetime.Now.toString() and see if it has the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the articles and whitepapers below. I think they should give you enough concrete performance considerations to explore, and likely some very practical settings to tweak, optimize, or change.

[Performance Tuning WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273113.aspx)

[Optimizing WCF Web Service Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee377061%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)

[Using ServiceThrottlingBehavior to Control WCF Service Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114.aspx)

[Transport Quotas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731078.aspx)

[Optimizing IIS Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee377050%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)

[ASP.NET Performance Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668225.aspx)

[A Performance Comparison of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) with Existing Distributed Communication Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx)

Comment: I think this is pretty list of links, but could you expand on some of the specific techniques you used that you found helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a full memory dump during the 13 seconds (or several using procdump) and then acutally look at what is occurring in the process (windbg and sos.dll).  Then, you can narrow down which code is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that the dictionary tree is only loaded once, into cache?  You're not loading it on every call are you?

Comment: its loaded every call at the moment (this is first prototype), but that is not the problem. Trie load time takes 417ms.